# what are ObservableCollection

Tags: silverlight, observablecollection

I'm a new SilverLight developer, 
can anybody tell me in brief (**what are the ObservableCollection**) ?

thank you very much.

Comment: i will not vote you down, but that's definitely not an adequate question .. try to study the documentation and read tutorials - and if then there are still things unclear, post here :)

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN documentation on ObservableCollection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx):

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when
>   items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

I've used this in a WPF grid where the ItemSource was bound to such an ObservableCollection. When rows in my grids where added, removed (or refreshed), the grid would visually reflect the same.

A sample program is available at the link above.